# Codeigniter datatable checkbox auto checks the check-all checkbox

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

I have used checkbox to select full row using datatable jquery like this

```
 columnDefs: [{
        className: 'select-checkbox custon-user',
        targets: 0,
        'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
        }
    }],
    'select': {
        style: 'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
```

But when I click any of the checkbox of any row of datatable, the check-all checkbox auto checked. For example, If I click 2nd row checkbox, then check-all checkbox(on table heading) auto checked.

I tried to uncheck it using custom jquery, but since it's server side datatable, html generates after page load, so my custom jquery is not putting any impact on checkbox.

How I can stop check-all checkbox from auto checked?

Comment: Have a look at this snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw/

Comment: @b126 In this fiddle, when we click on any checkbox, then check-all checkbox gets horizontal/minus_symbol line but in my code, it gets check symbol. This is the main issue. I couldn't figure out why it shows check symbol on check-all checkbox while is fiddle is shows horizontal line symbol on checking any checkbox.

Comment: I would first check the version of the jquery-datatables-checkboxes if you are using this extension. See https://github.com/gyrocode/jquery-datatables-checkboxes
Secondly, verify the version of jquery and datatables
Finally, check for Javascript error/conflict preventing your script to complete properly. Is there something strange in the JS console of the DEV mode of your browser?